# Unable to sent mail in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

I have installed SQL server 2008 r2 express in new machine.
I have configured some profile in msdb database.
I tried

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @profile_name = 'DBMAIL',
                @recipients  = 'sakthivels@c8888ht.com',
                @subject      = 'Subject',
                @body         = 'Body of the mail',
                @body_format  = 'TEXT'
```

Unable to sent  mail in sql server 2008 r2
select mailitem_id,sent_status,sent_date from msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems  order by mailitem_id desc
it return as failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to forget this process and now the problem get solved.

[sysmail_create_user_credential_sp] 'abc@gmail.com','password',0
select * from sys.credentials

credential_id=65536

need to update in sysmail_server table with credential_id=65536

Answer (score 0):

Sorry @Sakthivel but Express edition has no support for DB mail. You need at least standard edition.

Comment: I have sent already lot of mails, the problem is after installed sql server 2008 r2 in new PC it has raise the issue.

Comment: and now it get solved. create the credential for my gmail account it get solved.